# QtCreator -- show a list of member functions of a class?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, qt-creator

Ｉrecently just switched to QtCreator for C++ programming.

I am curious, how do I see a list of the member functions/variables of a class on the right hand side of the screen? I think a lot of IDEs (such as Eclipse) provide this feature and it's quite useful for helping to understand new code.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by using Sidebar (To see sidebar. **Select Window->Show Sidebar**)

In Side-bar panel, there is a list option on top-right, **select "Class View"** and that's it!

[image]

Comment: How can i find my class in this view? When i try Ctrl + F, it searches every occurent of word for example in methods argument.

Comment: @user3191398, you could right-click any identifier and select "Find Usages". Ctrl-F is text search while "Find Usages" uses clang based symbol parsing to get you the desired results.

Comment: I think in older version Class View used to automatically show members of the current class (identified by the caret/typing cursor position in the Editor). Now in Qt Creator 4.7.2 Class View lists all classes which is unhandy to me because it requires manual search. I think this is what @user3191398 asked. Is it possible to bring this functionality back?